# Reduce size of text in slack message

Tags: text, format, slack-api

Is there a way to reduce the size of the text in slack messages just the way we have ways to make the text bold/italics?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The Slack markup does not include a feature for changing the font size. Your only formatting options are:

- Bold
- Italic
- Strike-through
- Quotes
- Inline Code
- Lists

See [Message Formatting (API docs)](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#message_formatting) and [Format your messages (Help Center)](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-how-can-i-add-formatting-to-my-messages-#strikethrough) for more details.

Another thought: If your aim is to reduce the size of your overall message appearing in a Slack channel I would suggest taking a look at attachments. Those will automatically be shortened and shown with an "Show more" option if its text exceeds 700 chars.

Answer (score 7):

For version 4.10.1 the best I was able to come up with was superscript.  I typed out my text in a word processor, turned it into superscript, and copy/pasted it back into Slack.  This is what it looked like.  It's quite small.

[image: superscript text in slack image]

Comment: strictly speaking this isn't really formatted in "superscript", as in a text styling.  This is replacing your characters with obscure unicode characters are smaller version.  It totally works but has limitations since there's not a tiny version of every letter/character.